# How can I change the numbering of sections?

Tags: numbering, theorems

My code below compiles a document and so far it prints, e.g.:

Definition 1.1

Example 1.1

Example 1.2

Corollary 1.1

But how can I change this to the following:

Definition 1.1

Example 1.2

Example 1.3

Corollary 1.4

This is the code I am using presently:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\title{TITLE}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{amsmath} % provides numberwithin (and lots more)
\usepackage{lipsum} 

\theoremstyle{plain}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\theoremstyle{remark}
\theoremstyle{plain}

\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}
\newtheorem*{axiom}{Axiom}
\newtheorem{exercise}{Exercise}

\numberwithin{definition}{section}
\numberwithin{theorem}{section}
\numberwithin{corollary}{section}
\numberwithin{lemma}{section}
\numberwithin{example}{section}

\begin{document}
\section{Section A}
\subsection{Subsection A}
\begin{definition}
blah blah
\begin{example}
blah blah
\end{example}
\subsection{Subsection B}
\subsection{Subsection C}
\subsection{Subsection D}
\subsection{Subsection E}
\section{Section B}
\subsection{Subsection A}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is covered in any good introduction to LaTeX: `\newtheorem{theorem}[definition]{Theorem}` and similarly for the other structures, so they'll share the counter with `definition`.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thank you for the edit; I've been wondering how to get the code in a shaded box like that. Did you have to press the Tab key for each line of code upon editing my post?

Comment: @dragon: No, I marked your code with the mouse and pressed `CTRL - K`  (Alternatively you can click on the `{}` - symbols button in the editor)

Comment: strictly speaking, these things aren't sections, but theorem-like objects.  you might want to consider adjusting the question text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it is. Note you don't have to load `amsmath` since `mathtools` does it for you:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\title{TITLE}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
 \usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\theoremstyle{plain} 
\newtheorem{theorem}[definition]{Theorem}
\newtheorem{corollary}[definition]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{lemma}[definition]{Lemma} 
\theoremstyle{remark} 
\newtheorem{example}[definition]{Example}
\newtheorem{exercise}[definition]{Exercise}
\newtheorem*{axiom}{Axiom}

 \numberwithin{definition}{section}

\begin{document}

\section{Section A}
\subsection{Subsection A}

\begin{definition} blah blah
\end{definition}
\begin{example} blah blah
\end{example}

\subsection{Subsection B}
\begin{theorem}
  A theorem. 
\end{theorem}

\subsection{Subsection C}

\subsection{Subsection D}

\subsection{Subsection E}

\section{Section B}

\subsection{Subsection A}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You should note that issuing a row of `\theoremstyle` commands is completely useless, because the last one prevails. So these will all be `plain`. A `\newtheorem` inherits the attributes from the *current* theorem style.

Comment: @Bernard Wow, this works! I'm new to LaTeX in general, so I did have a question: Why do we add `[theorem]` to each `\newtheorem` except the first one (the one with "Theorem" itself)? My first instinct was to add `[definition]` to each (except to the one with "Definition" itself) but that apparently didn't work on my end.

Comment: It means each such \newtheorem shares the `Theorem` counter. Otherwise, each has its own counter. You can share a counter that has previously been defined.  I've updated my answer to illustrate how styles work, and used `[definition]` instead. Probably you forgot to change `\numberwithin{theorem}{section}` to `\numberwithin{definition}{section}`.

Comment: the `amsthm` documentation has recently been thoroughly overhauled, and one of the new sections is a quite extensive treatment of numbering.  the new documentation -- `amsthdoc.pdf` -- will be included in tex live 2015, but in the meantime, it's available [from ctan](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amslatex/amscls/doc/amsthdoc.pdf).